# Countable Regular Spaces Which Are Not Monotonically Normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In Heath, Lutzer, Zenor, *Monotonically Normal Spaces*, Trans. Am. Math. Soc., **178**, 481-493, (1973), the authors discuss an example of a countable regular space which is not monotonically normal (see Example 7.3 on pg. 490). The example is of some interest as it immediately indicates the existence of a countable regular space which is not stratifiable.

No construction of the space is supplied, and instead a reference is given to the first named author's earlier paper *An easier proof that a certain countable space is not stratifiable*, which appears in conference proceedings that I could not find in print.

> Does anyone know the construction of the space discussed above?

I would also be happy to see any other construction of a countable regular space which is not monotomically normal (or equivalently not stratifiable). Indeed, another example of such a space was supposedly constructed by van Douwen (see *Nonstratifiable regular quotients of separable stratifiable spaces*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 52 (1975), 457–460) although again references appear in lieu of details. This time to a pair of the author's preprints which may have never actually seen the light of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completely revised.**

In [*The cometrizability of generalized metric spaces*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10987v3), Section $4$, Taras Banakh and Yaryna Stelmakh construct a regular topology $\tau$ of weight $\omega_1$ on $\Bbb Q$ such that $\langle\Bbb Q,\tau\rangle$ is not cometrizable and hence not stratifiable. (I have not yet gone through the construction.)

I had not previously encountered cometrizability; $X$ is cometrizable if $X$ admits a weaker metrizable topology such that  each point of $X$ has a (not  necessarily open) nbhd base consisting of sets that are closed in the metrizable topology. Apparently P.M. Gartside and E.A. Reznichenko proved in *Near metric properties of function spaces*, Fund. Math. 164:2 (2000), 97–114, that every stratifiable space is cometrizable.

Comment: @Tyrone: No, at some point between reading the question and going off to dig around, I seem to have mentally inverted the desired condition, so you should ignore the answer (which I’m about to delete).

Comment: @Tyrone: I have, however, now found an example. The recursive construction, which I’ve only had time to scan briefly, is a bit involved but doesn’t appear to be too terribly hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the help Brian. I shall have a go at your suggestions and accept you answer when I figure something out.

Comment: @Tyrone: You’re welcome; with luck I may find time actually to go through the thing!

Comment: Ok. I found what I was looking for. Going though Banakh's paper (I'm a big fan of his work) I found a reference to *Monotone Normality and
Paracompactness in Scattered Spaces* by P. Nyikos and S. Purisch. The authors construct a countable, collectionwise normal space $X$ which is not monotonically normal. The underlying set of $X$ is $\omega\times(\omega+1)\sqcup\{p\}$ and its topology is zero-dimensional and not locally compact at $p$. It injects into $(\omega+1)^2$ so is cometrisable, but it is not stratifiable as it is not monotonically normal (it is necessarily semi-stratifiable).

Comment: Time permitting I will type up the example here to accompany your answer.

Comment: @Tyrone: Thanks for letting me know. I’m not surprised: Steve Purisch was doing a lot with scattered spaces around that time.